# Set format of date, concatenated with string

Tags: excel, google-sheets, excel-2010

I would like to get the following string as a date formatted:

```
="Status: "& TODAY()
```

However, I get:

```
Status: 42418
```

I would like to get:

```
Status: 18.02.2016
```

I already tried to change the format to Date or use the `Datevalue` function.

Any suggestions, how to get the current date correctly formatted?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can format the date manualy with DAY(),MONTH() and YEAR() function.

```
="Status: "& DAY(TODAY())&"."& MONTH(TODAY())&"."&YEAR(TODAY())
```

Or you can use the TEXT() function to do the formatting.

```
="Status: " & TEXT(TODAY();"DD.MM.YYYY")
```

Answer (score 0):

A better way to do this is just change the number format.

Change your cell formula back to `=today()`

Select the **Format** menu, then **Number**, **More Formats**, and finallay **More date and time formats**

Then set the custom format as followed:

[image: Date format dialog]

The benefit of this is that the value of your cell is still a date, not string

## EDIT

This answer primarily illustrate separation of *presentation* and *data*.

Think of currency. *2* is data, and *US$ 2.00* is presentation of the data. When you compute the value, you just want to put the number 2 instead of a formula like `= "US$" & data & ".00"`

This makes the spreadsheet more robust to any future change where you want to reference your computed values in other cells.

Another example would be win-loss computation. It's better to output the value TRUE/FALSE or 1,0,-1  and then have a custom format to convert the value to text. (In this case, the format rule is `"WIN";"LOSS";"DRAW"`)

Comment: But the goal was to generate a string with some text and an added date.